# Iterating through the children of an ItemControl

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, itemscontrol

I have been using : **itemControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(Index)** to get children of the Item Control. I want to further iterate through each children of the ItemControl, e.g :

Var item = itemControl.itemControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
now I want to access every elements inside the first child of itemControl.

Comment: Hope it helps...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx#tree_traversal

Comment: Try this one too...http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2115888&seqNum=2

Comment: Please refer following post 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type